# Buck converter inductor selection: maximum switch current limit vs output current

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I need to select an inductor for this buck [converter](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1765fd.pdf). Its output current is 3 A and maximum switch current limit is 6 A. As far as I know, I need to select an inductor whose current ratings (both DC and saturation) greater than 3 A.

When selecting an inductor, do I need to select an inductor whose current rating (DC) is greater than 6 A and current - saturation (Isat) greater than 3 A?

Comment: The data sheet says how to select an inductor. Did you read that part?

Comment: @Justme,I checked it what I understood is inductor DC current must be larger than switch current and saturation current must be larger than output current.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You should select the inductor based on your load, the switch current limit doesn't really come into play.  So, find your worst-case load current, and add some extra for margin.   Assuming the load is 3A, I would look for a 5A or 6A rated inductor.

Comment: You usually set the maximum peak current limit of your switcher or controller above the maximum operating current and select a magnetic capable to sustain this peak in fault condition, without saturating at high temp. Here, considering the 6-A limit for a 3-A nominal, you may end up with a magnetic much bigger than what is truly necessary. But for the general case, you make sure the inductor stays away from saturation also in fault conditions for a safe and reliable design.

Comment: @Troutdog,May I know the value you suggested (5A or 6A) is the DC current or saturation current.

Comment: @Hari - Definitely DC current.  Generally speaking, a higher current rating will be more efficient. The trade off is physical size (as mentioned by Verbal Kint above).  If you find that the physical size of a 5A (DC rated) inductor is acceptable for your design, then I would recommend that.  That will give you plenty of margin.  Yes, you can optimize further, but do you need to?